# Array of structs - C bad value

Tags: c, arrays, struct, strtok

I'm facing a quite interesting problem in C.
So I have a struct which looks like this:

```
struct Question {
    int year;
    char* month;
    char* day;
    char* hour;
    char* minute;
    char* second;
    char* question;
    int answerCount;
    char* answers[1024];
} questions[100];
```

There, I'm initializing an array of Question structs called questions, with the size of 100.
So I want to fill that array from a file looking like this:

```
2017 04 01 12 38 00 OK? 2 NO NO
2017 04 01 14 15 00 WHAT? 4 YES YES YES YES
```

The structure:
year month day hour minute second question answercount answers

I'm processing the file like this:

```
...
int id = 0;
int j;

char line[2048];
while ( (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) != NULL) {


        char* p = strtok(line, " ");
        char* tokens[1024];
        char* token;

        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        while((p != NULL)) {
            switch(counter) {
                case 0: questions[id].year = atoi(p); break; // year
                case 1: questions[id].month = p; break; // month
                case 2: questions[id].day = p; break; // day
                case 3: questions[id].hour =p; break; // hour
                case 4: questions[id].minute = p; break; // minute
                case 5: questions[id].second = p; break; // seconds
                case 6: questions[id].question = p; break; // question
                case 7: 
                questions[id].answerCount = atoi(p);
                int qcount = atoi(p);
                int k;
                int l = j;
                //printf("count : %d", qcount);
                for (k = 0; k < qcount; ++k) {
                    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    ++l;
                    questions[id].answers[k] = p;
                }
                break;
                default: break;
            }
            p = strtok(NULL, " ");
            ++counter;
        }
        ++id;

    }
    fclose(fp);
...
```

After that, if I printf the questions[0].question element in the while loop, I get "OK?", however if I print the same thing after the while loop, I get "WHAT?".
I've spent a lot of time thinking what I might do wrong, but no success.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you expect the string "OK?" to be stored somewhere for later printing. Where?

Comment: Well in questions[0].question. I'm making this assigning here: questions[id].question = p;

Comment: questions[0].question is a pointer. It cannot store a string, it only points to a string stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your structure, you are having many char pointers, for all of them you are assigning pointer values returned from `strtok`. You need to understand that the contents of pointers returned by `strtok` will change overtime with each call to `strtok` and you are not supposed to store those pointers for future use. Refer to man of strtok.

You need to either change the `char *` in your structure to `char` array or alloc memory for those `char *` and then copy the contents of the pointer to returned by `strtok` to it. Otherwise you may end up getting weird behavior from your program.

Comment: Ohh.. thank you for your reply! Managed to solve it, and understood the real problem here. Thanks Sir!

Comment: Most Welcome! : )

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
char* answers[1024];
```

Is an array of 1024 pointers to strings, but does not contain any storage for those strings.  So when you do this:

```
questions[id].answers[k] = p;
```

You are not copying the answer, but merely assigning a pointer to it.  Since `p` ultimately is a pointer to somewhere within `line`, which is only allocated once before the loop begins, you are overwriting the strings in `line` each time through the loop.  So the referents of your `answers` is being modified.

You could either change `answers` to be a 2D array of char, in which case the maximum length of each answer will be limited, or use `strdup()` or similar to allocate memory for each answer, and `free()` it at the end.

Comment: His question is about printing questions[0].question and your answer is about "question.answers". Though, I agree that you have a valid point. ;)

Comment: Oh thank you for that, however this wasn't my original issue. Thanks for your suggestion though, I changed that.